# How to push to multi-dimensional array if value does not exist in javascript

Tags: arrays, typescript, for-loop, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array that stores information on questions and answers given by a user and relies on 3 checks.

- if the array is empty it pushes the initial data set
- if a question number exists in the array,  its associated answer is updated
- if a question number does not exist, the question information and answer are pushed to the   array

I have managed to do the first 2 checks, but I am having trouble with the third check. When I try to push new question & answer information it pushes multiple repetitions instead of just one data set.

The function I am using is:

```
getBoolvalue(boolvalue, optionIndex, questionnNumber, option)
{
    if(this.answerboolvalues[0] == null)
    {
        this.answerboolvalues.push([questionnNumber, optionIndex, option, boolvalue]);
        console.log(this.answerboolvalues);
    
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Array length : " + this.answerboolvalues.length);
        console.log("Array item : " + this.answerboolvalues[1][2]);
    
        for(let j = 0; j < this.answerboolvalues.length; j++)
        {
            if(this.answerboolvalues[j][0] == questionnNumber)  
            {
                if(this.answerboolvalues[j][1] == optionIndex)
                {
                    this.answerboolvalues[j][3] = boolvalue;
                    console.log(this.answerboolvalues);
                }
            }
            else if(this.answerboolvalues[j][0] != questionnNumber) 
            {
                this.answerboolvalues.push([questionnNumber, optionIndex, option, boolvalue]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much cleaner to use `.find` to see if the element exists in the array. If it does, you can mutate the found item as needed, otherwise push a new array.

There's no need for the `if(this.answerboolvalues[0] == null)` check, because if the array is empty, no elements will be found, so it'll be pushed to the array due to condition 3 anyway.

Also fix the `questionNumber` misspelling, typos are an easy source of bugs:

```
getBoolvalue(boolValue, optionIndex, questionNumber, option) {
  const foundItem = this.answerboolvalues.find(
    subarr => subarr[0] === questionNumber && subarr[1] === optionIndex
  );
  if (foundItem) {
    foundItem[3] = boolValue;
  } else {
    this.answerboolvalues.push([questionNumber, optionIndex, option, boolValue]);
  }
}
```

But this data structure is strange. Consider having `answerboolvalues` be an object indexed by `questionNumber` instead, or having it be an array of objects instead of an array of arrays:

```
getBoolvalue(boolValue, optionIndex, questionNumber, option) {
  const foundItem = this.answerboolvalues.find(
    subarr => subarr.questionNumber === questionNumber && subarr.optionIndex === optionIndex
  );
  if (foundItem) {
    foundItem.boolValue = boolValue;
  } else {
    this.answerboolvalues.push({ questionnNumber, optionIndex, option, boolValue });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, thanks for the response. The question basically follow a 'select which of the following statements are true/false' format with multiple statements associated with drop downs from which a user selects which are true or false so the question number is one index then another index is for question statements to match answers to

Comment: Consider a data structure indexed by question number then, eg `{ 2: [true, false, true, true] }` corresponding to question 2 where the first option is true, second is false, etc. That'd make a lot more sense than the current approach

Comment: I had considered that but the problem is not all the questions are true/false for example out of 6 questions questions 2 and question 4 would be true false so cant use question number as an index

Comment: Then have a different data format for those, while having an array of true/falses for these.